# Show that $\max _{x \in[-1,1]}|P(x)| \geq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ without Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: inequality, polynomials, upper-lower-bounds, chebyshev-polynomials

For every monic polynomial $P$ of degree $n$ (with leading coefficient 1), it is well-known that
$$\max _{x \in[-1,1]}|P(x)| \geq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}.$$
A standard proof uses [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).

Is there a proof which does not use Chebyshev polynomials?

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259428/proof-of-a-lower-bound-of-the-norm-of-an-arbitrary-monic-polynomial

Comment: It looks like there was an answer posted but it was removed---I believe because there was a mistake in the induction.

Comment: @JakeMirra Right - I mistakenly assumed that my $Q$ would necessarily be monic. Working on a fix right now. ;-)

Comment: @FranklinPezzutiDyer it suffices to show that the leading coefficient is (without loss of generality) less than 1 in absolute value

Comment: Equality holds in $\max _{x \in[-1,1]}|P(x)| \geq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ exactly if $P$ is a Chebyshev polynomial, therefore I assume that any proof must be somehow connected to the Chebyshev polynomials.

Comment: @MartinR Eh... I don't know if I buy that logic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have come up with a (somewhat strange) proof that uses only the first Chebyshev polynomials
$$Q_2(x) = 2x^2 - 1$$
I will use the fact that this is a surjection from $[-1, 1] \to [-1, 1]$.

Define
$$M(n) = 2^{n-1}\inf_P \max_{x \in [-1, 1]}  |P(x)|.$$
where $P$ goes over monic polynomials of degree $n$.

The key steps of the proof are two facts.

Fact 1: $M(2n) \leq M(n)^2.$

Proof: If $P$ is a degree $n$ polynomial with $\max_{x \in [-1, 1]}  |P(x)| = \alpha$, then the polynomial
$$P'(x) = 2^{-1} \alpha^{2} Q_2(\alpha^{-1}P(x))$$
is of degree $2n$ and satisfies $\max_{x \in [-1, 1]}  |P’(x)| = 2^{-1} \alpha^{2}$. Taking $\alpha$ to be sufficiently close to $M(n)$, we get $M(2n) \leq M(n)^2$.

Fact 2: $M(n) \leq M(2n).$

Proof: If $P'$ is a degree $2n$ polynomial with $\max_{x \in [-1, 1]} |P'(x)| = \alpha$, then $P'(x) + P'(-x)$ is an even polynomial. Thus we can write
$$P'(x) + P'(-x) = 2^{-n+1} P(Q_2(x))$$
where $P$ is some monic polynomial of degree $n$. Thus we have $\max_{x \in [-1, 1]} |P(x)| \leq 2^{n}\alpha$. Taking $\alpha$ to be sufficiently close to $M(2n)$, we get $M(n) \leq M(2n)$.

Combining the two parts, we conclude that $M(n) \leq M(n)^2$, so $M(n)$ is either at least $1$ or equal to $0$. It suffices to show that $M(n)$ is not equal to $0$. This is easy: for any monic $P$ of degree $n$, one can find some $x \in [-1, 1]$ that is distance at least $1/n$ from each root, so $M(n) \geq (1/n)^n$.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but how do we know, in fact 2, that every even polynomial of degree 2n can be written as a polynomial of degree n in terms of $Q_2(x)$ (with coefficients that are integer multiples of $2^{-n}$)? Is this true about say $x^2+1$?

Comment: Also I think there's a typo with the $2^{-n} \alpha$ in the second to last paragraph...should be $2^n \alpha$

Comment: Nevermind my first comment. If anyone else is wondering you can do this by a type of polynomial long division where you form the largest term and then you only have to be able to construct a polynomial of smaller and smaller degree until the degree is 0 and you can add a constant